# Function returns the longest number from each nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

The code:

```js
function longestfour(arr) {
  let w;
  let newArr = [];
  let nw = 0;
  for (let r in arr) {
    w = arr[r];
    for (let rr in w) {
      if (w[rr] > nw) {
        nw = w[rr];
      }

    }
    newArr.push(nw);
  }
  return newArr;
}
console.log(longestfour([
  [-334, -6, -243, -87],
  [7, 65, 46, 3],
  [8, 55, 76, 2]
]));
```

The problem:
Its not working when nested array elements are negative..!!
It should return [-6,65,76]

Comment: what is *longest* in this context?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on forming questions that best enable the community to provide you with helpful guidance.  What `longestfour` is intended to do is not immediately evident from the title-- could you include a description of the intended behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your are starting the comparsion with `nw=0`... Then all negative numbers are less than 0. Only change it to `let nw = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER ;` then your code works fine.

Comment: Don't you think it is better to take the first value of the array, and do the comparisions?

Comment: Thank you so much, I was realizing the problem but didn't know how to initialize the variabl (nw)..

Answer (score 1):

Please use Math.max function. Then the code becomes more simple.

```js
    function longestfour(arr) {
      return arr.map(val => Math.max(...val));
    } 
    console.log(longestfour([[-334,-6,-243,-87],[7,65,46,3],[8,55,76,2]]));
```

Comment: I want to use (for loop) with no help of ready methods.. 